# nested loops pattern java

Tags: java, nested-loops, bluej

I have been struggling with this pattern,trying to use only the code required for a nested FOR loop. I am required not to use patterns,just a nested **for** loop:

```
123454321
1234 4321
123   321
12     21
1       1
```

The code required is Java and I am using *BlueJ* compiler.

Comment: required by whom? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a homework

Comment: @ling.s there is no such thing as off-topic, because its homework. The problem is that it doesn't show any effort. That's why I downvoted it (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253792/stack-overflow-and-homework-questions)

Comment: Since no code is provided, it's not clear what you're struggling with.

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to this. I'll try and be more precise next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. A nested for loop, which gives the desired output.

```
String s[] = new String[]{"123454321","1234 4321","123   321","12     21","1       1"};
for(int i=0; i<=0;i++)// for the nested loop
  for(String x:s)
    System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Very funny answer I'd ever seen

Comment: @vefthym I hope you know what sarchasm is.

Comment: @ineedhelpinlogic I do, but I was confused when you accepted this answer :) I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider revising your question and be more specific. Also, you don't really need a nested loop, it seems inefficient this way. However, since you require that, here is a naive solution:

```
final int LIMIT = 5; //LIMIT has to be <10

//first construct a char array whose maximum number is LIMIT
char[] input = new char[2*LIMIT-1];     
//if you use Arrays.fill(input, ' '); here, and a print in the first loop, you get the reverse answer (try it)           
for (int i = 0; i<LIMIT; ++i) {
    input[i] = Character.forDigit(i+1, 10); //converts int to char (in decimal)
    input[(2*LIMIT)-i-2] = input[i];        
}


//next print the array, each time removing the chars that are within an increasing range from the middle element of the array    
for (int i = LIMIT; i > 0; --i) {            
    for (int j = 0; j < LIMIT-i; ++j) { //you don't really need a nested loop here
        input[LIMIT-1+j] = ' '; //replace the j chars following the middle with whitespace
        input[LIMIT-1-j] = ' '; ////replace the j chars before the middle with whitespace
    }
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

An alternative, without a nested loop, would be:

```
//after the first loop
String line = input.toString();

System.out.println(line);
for (int i = LIMIT; i>0; --i) {
    line = line.replace(Character.forDigit(i, 10), ' ');
    System.out.println(line);
}
```